# Fail to authenticate user based on access token - MS Graph API C#

Tags: azure-active-directory, access-token, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to get the current user's datas with Graph API. I'd like to get the access token and append it to the request message. So I'd like to skip the login UI. Some reason I get the (401) Unauthorized error, invalid user... I registered my app(mvc) AAD, and the secret, client id, tenant id from there.

This is the method to get the token:

```
    public static string GetToken()
    {
        string authority = "https://graph.microsoft.com/{tenantID}/oauth2/token";
        string clientId = "client id";
        string secret = "client secret";
        string resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";

        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, secret);
        AuthenticationResult authResult = authContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientCredential);
        return authResult.AccessToken;
    }
```

And this is the code, where I append the access token:

```
    public static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedClient()
    {
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
            new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                async (requestMessage) =>
                {
                    string accessToken = GetToken();
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                }));
        return graphClient;
    }
```

Any advice would be helpful, beacuse I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of access token issued by Azure AD.

The first one is **delegate-token** which used to delegate the user to operate user's resource.

And the other one is **application token** which usually used to perform the operation for the resource of all organization and there is no user context(current user) in this token. So we shouldn't use this token to perform the resource as `me` which required the user context.

To operate the resources using the **application token**, we need to specify the  user using users collection like code below:

```
string userId = "";
var user = graphserviceClient.Users[userId].Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

Comment: I have methods, like that. var user = graphClient.Users[uid].Request().Select("displayName").GetAsync(); and I call it after called GetAuthenticatedClient method like that:
               GraphServiceClient graphClient = SDKHelper.GetAuthenticatedClient();

                ViewBag.Name = graphService.GetMyName(graphClient);

Comment: To read the from users resource from Azure active directory, we need to grant the `User.Read.All; Directory.Read.All;` permission for the app. Please check the permission on the Azure portal to ensure you have granted the enough permission. You can check the these permissions by decoding the token from [this site](https://jwt.io/) after you modified the permission.

Comment: Please make sure that the relative scope presents in the token? And if the issue still exits, would you mind sharing the detailed error message?

Comment: Relative scope?

Comment: Yes, you can check the `roles` claim by decode the token from [this site](https://jwt.io/).

Comment: Yes, I did this. Roles are ok.
"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. "
And complains for this line: AuthenticationResult authResult = authContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientCredential);

Comment: What's the detailed error message about 401 error? There should be the detailed error message about 401. If not, you can try to capture the request using the Fiddler and check raw response.

Comment: There isn't 401 unauthorized message, but when I'd like to get a user's display name for example, it says "Resource 'email' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."

Comment: This property was existed when you assign the user with Office 365 licencees etc. If you want to get/set the email of users without using the Office 365, you can use the `otherMails` property. More detail about the user entity, you can refer [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity).

Answer (score 1):

Was this solved?  If not, I dont think you are using the right authority.  If your resource is "https://graph.microsoft.com/" then your authority should be "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/v2.0/token" or the same authority but swap "common" for your azure AD tenant ID.  Info from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview)